# jquery - showing box with if statement by click on button when field is completed - quiz creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I'm desperately trying to create something very simple for you!

#### Here's my problem:

I'd like to create a small quiz in which when someone writes anything in a field (), and then click the button "ok" (not sure if I should use a  or a ), then 3 possibilities arise (for each case a box appearing under the field input):

1. The answer is exact and correctly written: then the text will be "Great job!"
2. The answer is almost correct, meaning that the word is not correctly written (we can define if necessary "almost answers"): the text will be "Almost there..."
3. The answer is completely wrong, the text will be "Try again!"

Right now I have that:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>To whom it belongs?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="#" alt="Tim's coat" width="100%"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="answer-box">
                    <input type="text" class="field-answer" placeholder="Write it there!">
                    <button id="showresult" class="button-answer" value="Ok">OK</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="res" id="switch">Great job!</div>
                    <div class="res" id="switch2">Almost there...</div>
                    <div class="res" id="switch3">Try again!</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var artist = ["abba"];
    var almostartist = ["abaa", "aaba", "aabaa"];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.field-answer').bind('keyup', function(){
            if("#showresult").click(function() {
                if($.inArray($(this).val().toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^\w\s\-\_!@#\$%\^\&*\\")\(+=._-]/g, ''), artist) >= 0){
                    $('#switch').show('good');
                }
                else if($.inArray($(this).val().toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^\w\s\-\_!@#\$%\^\&*\\")\(+=._-]/g, ''), almostartist) >= 0){
                    $('#switch2').addClass('soso');
                if{
                    $('#switch3').addClass('non');
                }
                else {
                    $('#switch3').removeClass('non');
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

But of course this is not working...

In case, my CSS is here:

```
    .res {
    display: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #490058;
    height: 75px;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 140%;
}

    .res.good {
        display: block;
    }

    .res.soso {
        display: block;
    }

    .res.non {
        display: block;
    }

    .answer-box {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .button-answer {
        border: none;
        background-color: #490058;
        color: white;
        font-size: 120%;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 8px;
        left: 260px;
    }

    .field-answer {
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        background-color: transparent;
        max-width: 230px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        outline: 0;
    }
```

Someone could help me to figure that out, please?
I'm quite sure I'm not far, but cannot solve it...

If you need more precisions on stuffs, please don't hesitate! ;)

Thanks guys!

Baptiste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach - no better than any other suggestion - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NTUx9/).

JS

```
var artist = ["abba"];
var almostartist = ["abaa", "aaba", "aabaa"];

$('.field-answer').focus(function(){
      $('.res').css('display', 'none');
      $(':input').val('');
});

$('#showresult').on('click', function(){
                                        useranswer = $('.field-answer').val();
                                        useranswer = useranswer.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^\w\s\-\_!@#\$%\^\&*\\")\(+=._-]/g);
                                        if( $.inArray( useranswer, artist ) === 0 )
                                           { 
                                             $('#switch1').css('display', 'block');
                                            }
                                         else if ( $.inArray( useranswer, almostartist ) >= 0 )
                                           { 
                                             $('#switch2').css('display', 'block');
                                            }
                                         else //if ( $.inArray( useranswer, almostartist ) < 0 )
                                           {
                                            $('#switch3').css('display', 'block');
                                            }
                                             });
```

Answer (score 0):

your whole function is bound in to 'keyup' event.

keyup event only occurs once when key is released from pressed.

try deleting `bind('keyup', function)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to your problems.
Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/EGd27/2/)
In this script every time you click on the button the field text is compared with the values of the array
Depending on the value of the the corrisponding div is showed.
code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var artist = ["abba"];
    var almostartist = ["abaa", "aaba", "aabaa"];

    $("#showresult").click(function() {
        var text=$('.field-answer').val();
        if(artist.indexOf(text) > -1){
            $('#switch').show();
            }
        else if(almostartist.indexOf(text) > -1){
            $('#switch2').show();
            }
        else{$('#switch3').show();} 
    });

});
</script>
```

if you want the message appears on keyup you have to use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var artist = ["abba"];
    var almostartist = ["abaa", "aaba", "aabaa"];

    $(".field-answer").on('keyup',function() {
        $('.res').hide()
        var text=$('.field-answer').val().toLowerCase();
        if(artist.indexOf(text) > -1){
            $('#switch').show();
            }
        else if(almostartist.indexOf(text) > -1){
            $('#switch2').show();
            }
        else{$('#switch3').show();} 
    });

});
</script>
```

If you like one of these solutions remember to falg in green my answer ;) thanks.